# How to deal with pandas reading JSON too large integer values will be the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a JSON file where the value column is a large integer. The integer value will be the same when I read it with pandas.

An example

```
import pandas as pd

line = '{"value":"383088110696696320"}\n{"value":"383088110696696321"}'
df = pd.read_json(line,lines=True)
print(df)

                value
0  383088110696696320
1  383088110696696320
```

I've tried to read it properly in the following way, but it can't perform mathematical operations.

```
df = pd.read_json(line,lines=True,dtype=False)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
df['value'] = df['value']-383088110696696320
print(df)
   value
0    0.0
1    0.0
```

How should I deal with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are on a 32 or 64 bit machine, but you should try to use `np.int64`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

line = '{"value":"383088110696696320"}\n{"value":"383088110696696321"}'
df = pd.read_json(line, lines=True, dtype=False)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(np.int64)
df['value'] = df['value'] - 383088110696696320
print(df)
#     value
#  0      0
#  1      1
```